# min-height does not work with body

Tags: html, css

Does min-height not work on body/html?

```
body, html
{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Accomplishes absolutely nothing (firebug reports the body,html tags height does not change at all)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

First, declare a doctype so you're in standards if you haven't already.

Now, the body can only be as high as the containing html, so you need to set HTML tag to 100% height, and body to min-height 100%. This works for me on Firefox.

```
html {height:100%} 
body {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, a follow up question: I have now set body to be min-height: 100%. Now I have another div inside body, and I want that to also be min-height:100%;, I did that but it isn't working.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about the best way to accomplish that in a cross-browser compliant way.

Comment: adding min-height to body does not work, even with html min-height 100%

Comment: @chovy You misread my answer as saying you only need `min-height`. In my example, I said `html {height:100%} body {min-height:100%}`. That should work, and it certainly did for Razor who accepted it.

Comment: this works, but then i get extra vertical scrolling. Beyond the height of the window.

Comment: @chovy without access to your css, I have no way of knowing how. perhaps extra padding?

Comment: No need to look. It's margin, padding or border. Look into [box-sizing: border-box](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Answer (score 29):

This worked for chrome 64 without setting a hard-coded height:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

body {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: unlike all the other answers on SO, this actually worked for next cases: 1) allow a div to be 100% of a body if there's free space. 2) doesn't limit body size to viewport size if there's a scroll. But how crossbrowser is it?

Comment: It seems min-height is widely supported (IE7 and higher, all mobile browsers)
https://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh,
flex-box will need IE10 and above:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.
You could potentially polyfill display:flex for IE8+ with scripts such as:
https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility or perhaps with postCSS.

Answer (score 10):

Not all browsers like min-height, try something like this to catch all browsers.

```
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
```

Comment: This is so true and your advice was the only thing that worked to me! thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem with just:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I used:

html, body {
min-height: 100vh;
}

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers work for me.

What I did:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  min-height:100%; 
  position:relative;
}
```

you must add