# html body is smaller than its contents

Tags: html, css

Here's a basic [illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/uZCKn/1/) of the problem:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
    html {width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red;}
    body {width: 100%; height: 100%; background: green;}
    
    .leftbar, .rightbar {height: 100%; background: blue;}

    .leftbar  {float: left;}
    .rightbar {float: right;}

    table {width: 100px; height: 800px; background: black; color: white;
           margin: 0 auto 0 auto;}
</style></head>
<body>
    <ul class="leftbar"><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>
    <ul class="rightbar"><li>alpha</li><li>beta</li></ul>
    <table><tbody><tr><td>blah blah</td></tr></tbody></table>
</body>
</html>​
```

We can immediately see that the floated `ul` elements are as tall as the `body` which contains them, the problem is that the `body` is not as tall as the `table` which it contains.

How do I make the `body` be big enough? In this example, I want the `leftbar` and `rightbar` to go all the way down, as far as scrolling allows, so you can never see any gap below them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tables. They're impure but they *work*.

The div-based solutions involve unacceptable compromises (absolute dimensions, loss of float).

Comment: _fsvo_ "work". It's short-sighted to think that just because they work for your particular use case they _must_ work for all other contexts in which your content will be accessed.

Comment: They work in the neccessary context, and the alternatives *don't*.

Comment: It doesn't reflect well on our community that we down-vote a valid answer that potentially solves the OP's problem, simply because it's out of fashion. Tables are difficult to maintain, and break normal flow, but they're an intelligent solution to several thorny layout problems, particularly in a pre-flexbox world. (As is `display: table;` on a normal block-level element.)

Answer (score 20):

Remove `height: 100%` from your `body` rule - this makes the body as tall as the viewport height (which is less than the contents height).

Comment: That makes the `body` taller, but the `ul` are still only the height of the viewport.

Comment: Makes sense. For `ul`s to fill up the `body`, it needs to have some definite height set. Set it to `800px`, same as its tallest child element.

Comment: This makes so much sense and totally fixed this randomly annoying issue I had on a site like a year ago. I switched it from height:100% to min-height:100% to account for pages where the body is shorter than the viewport. Thanks!

Comment: If you apply a background to a 100% container within that body, and content isn't as tall as the view port, your background will be cut, though. (if you use this approach)

Answer (score 6):

```
body{ height:100%; }
```

This appears to be a misunderstanding of the code.   A "100%" height is relative to something.  In other words "100% of what?"

What this does is set body = the size of the window.  in JSFiddle, it's the size of the rendered box.  On a browser, it would be 100% of the viewing window.

So, if shrink your browser window down to a tiny view space, 100% height will be 100% of the tiny size.  Which is accurate.

If you have content that's longer than that, well you run into the issues you see in your example.   Recall that the table is a child element, not a parent container.  CSS inherits from parents, not children.  So you have to make sure BODY remains dynamic in it's height setting.

*update*

Here's a JSFiddle for min-height on body; http://jsfiddle.net/uZCKn/1/  It need HTML height to be 100% to work.  Got that from here: [min-height does not work with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740722/min-height-does-not-work-with-body)

The only thing I can think of is a JavaScript to set the height of the side bars or to use faux-columns.  But there could be something else going on to get the left/right bar to fill it's containers height as well that I'm missing.

There's part of an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeLh/

To fix the body height not going all the way down change `body{height:100%}` to `min-height:100%`. If you care, this will not work in IE6. To fix your lists take the floats out. Add `position:relative` to the `body`, add `position:absolute` to `.leftbar, .rightbar` and set the positions as follows

```
.leftbar  {left:0; top:0;}
.rightbar {right:0; top:0;}
```

You can see it in the fiddle I linked above.

Comment: Ah, that's a good fix.  Make the side bars absolute position.

Answer (score 3):

remove

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

and add

```
body { height: fit-content; }
```

The other thing is to certificate that there is not child div's that is making the things smaller then it really should be.

Comment: `fit-content` is an experimental property that should not be used in production code in 2017.

Comment: @TylerH could you post some link to know more about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you use floats, you must use clearfix.
Example (overflow: hidden to parent div give you a simplest clear fix):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <ul class="leftbar">
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="rightbar">
        <li>alpha</li>
        <li>beta</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can google more clearfixes, especially for your case