# HTML and Body Viewport issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, height

I have a website at filmblurb.org.

The page-container of my site extends to the bottom of the window when you scroll out to make for a 100% CSS layout style, but for some reason even when the height is 100% for both the body and tag, those two elements go about halfway down the page and then stop when the viewport is zoomed out. When I'm profiling those elements in Google Inspect Element that is. My page-container is currently min-height: 100%, but that for some reason actually does extend to the bottom of the viewport when zoomed out.

I've also taken screenshots of what I'm seeing to give you a better idea. Here they are [link]i917.photobucket.com/albums/ad16/jtarr523/… (for the body) and

[image]

(for the HTML)...Both are not extending to the bottom.

Anybody know how to fix this?

I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean using the browser zoom feature (such as with cmd+"-")?

Comment: I said zoomed out, but I guess I meant when you scroll down on the page.

Answer (score 3):

`min-height: 100%` on the `html` element means that that element will be at least as tall as the viewport.  It does not mean that it will always extend to the bottom.  If you scroll down, then you may still be able to scroll below the bottom of the `<html>` element.

The only way to prevent this (short of JavaScript) is to ensure that all elements on the page (that is, everything that could possibly cause a scrollbar) is kept within the `html` element.  A simple way to force this is to put `overflow: hidden` on your `html` element:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If the problem is being caused by a float, then that will solve it.  If the problem is caused by an absolute-positioned element or a negative bottom margin on the last element, then that will replace your problem with a more serious one: the page will be cut off at the bottom of the `html` element.  You will then have to find the problem element some other way.

(The same applies to the `body` element; it will need its own `overflow: hidden;` to ensure that nothing can extend beyond it.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly if it would work with browser zoom, but in my experience (and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740722/min-height-does-not-work-with-body) question) you need to set the `html` tag `height` to `100%` if you are setting container elements to `min-height: 100%`.

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

Replace `body` with a reference to your main container and it should still work. As far as I can tell there are no adverse reactions to setting `html` to 100%; it doesn't cut the page off or mess up any other styles.

Like I said, I'm not 100% sure this is related to your problem, but it's probably worth a shot.