# Marking up content height/width using %?

Tags: html, css, height, width

I've been playing with front-end web design the past couple of days, mainly using floats/clearfix to position my content.  I've been marking up the width of the content using % and that has worked perfectly.

However, if I try to define the height as a percentage of the overall page, it fails to work, more accurately it seems to just wrap around what ever content is there and I have to define the height as a px value.

Is there a reason for this?  Is there a workaround where I can use a percentage value and it actually divides up the page?

Comment: To force height or width try `min-height` or `min-width` in your CSS --https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

Comment: I think you'll need to add some HTML and CSS to show what you have tried so far

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), don't edit question titles to include the word SOLVED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define the property `height` in `%` you need a previous definition on the parent `height`. Then if you have a parent with fixed `height` on `px` you can work with `%`; but if you want to work % in relation to the window or other % values you need to set a value for all parents.

Then if you want to work with the window % you need this:

HTML like:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">My div with 100% height</div>
</body>
```

CSS like:

```
/*Need to set all parents to 100%*/
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
/*Then set the container*/
#container {
   height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:
give the HTML tag in CSS 100% and then you  should try to set the body element in CSS to

```
display:block;
```

and give it

```
min-height:100%
```

see this topic too:

[min-height does not work with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740722/min-height-does-not-work-with-body)

br paulq

Comment: Thanks, that was 3/4 of the answer!
I gave the body a height of 100% and position:absolute, then all I had to do was add the min-height:60% and a position:relative.

Worked like a charm thanks