# min-height property not working as expected in css

Tags: html, css

I want the divs to extend to full height when the content doesn't fully occupy the entire body. If the content becomes larger, the div should also grow larger with that.

The following is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin:0;
}

.inner{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.outer{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    padding:40px;
}
</style>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatibus iure aspernatur maiores tempora deserunt reiciendis aliquid quod distinctio debitis eius, nostrum obcaecati modi cum. Possimus, eos nobis explicabo corporis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatibus iure aspernatur maiores tempora deserunt reiciendis aliquid quod distinctio debitis eius, nostrum obcaecati modi cum. Possimus, eos nobis explicabo corporis.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/rta62jsy/2/) is the link to JS Fiddle for the above code. I want the div to extend to full body height even when the content is small and also the divs should expand as the content increases.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740722/min-height-does-not-work-with-body) is a similar question, but the solution doesn't seem to work for me. I have read many similar questions, but none of them works for me. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804581/css-expand-float-child-div-height-to-parents-height might be helpful

Comment: use vh instead of % like : { height:100vh } . This may help yours.

Answer (score 1):

It's because height of the `body` block is not specified explicitly.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

My solution is set `inner`'s min-height to `100vh`

```css
body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin:0;
}

.inner{
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.outer{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: green;
    padding:40px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatibus iure aspernatur maiores tempora deserunt reiciendis aliquid quod distinctio debitis eius, nostrum obcaecati modi cum. Possimus, eos nobis explicabo corporis.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi voluptatibus iure aspernatur maiores tempora deserunt reiciendis aliquid quod distinctio debitis eius, nostrum obcaecati modi cum. Possimus, eos nobis explicabo corporis.
 
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.inner{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.outer{
    width: 70%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-height:calc(100% - 80px);
    background-color: green;
    padding:40px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arashgh/vj62o9nw/

Comment: Could you please explain to me why this works and not mine?

Comment: of course, because the body, html and the parent of the considered element must have a specified height,and min-height or max-height is not enough.